# Dygraphs library: Access to non-visible data in highlightCallback function possible?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

This is a question regarding the Dygraphs library.

When using the "visibility" method in order to suppress the rendering of certain variables of a multivariate time series, only the *visible* highlighted points get passed to the "highlightCallback" function (third parameter, named "points" in the documentation). It would be convenient if the user had access to all points in the callback function, i.e., *highlighted visible* points **and** points *that were highlighted if the corresponding variables were to be set visible*.

My question: Is there a functionality/work around to gain access to the coordinates of non-visible highlighted points within the (un)highlightCallback function?

In order to clarify the problem, here a quick example:

Let's assume we have the following multivariate time series

```
"time_index", "var1", "var2"\n
"1", "5.1", "0.3"\n
"2", "5.5", "0.2"\n
"3", "5.8", "0.1"
```

and a Dygraph object `g` using this dataset. We set

```
g.updateOptions({visibility: [true, false]});
```

and, therefore, the time series corresponding to `var1` is drawn whereas `var2` is hidden. Now assume that we want to draw a vertical line of length `var2` for each highlighted point of the time series `var1`, i.e.,

- a line from `(1,5.1)` to `(1,5.4)=(1,5.1+0.3)` when point `(1,5.1)` is highlighted
- a line from `(2,5.5)` to `(2,5.7)=(2,5.5+0.2)` when point `(2,5.5)` is highlighted
- a line from `(3,5.8)` to `(3,5.9)=(3,5.8+0.1)` when point `(3,5.8)` is highlighted

This would be done by using the highlightCallback function.

```
g.updateOptions({
highlightCallback: function(event, x, points, row, seriesName) {
draw_line(points[0],[points[0].xval,points[0].yval+points[1].yval]); 
//draw_line(point_start,point_end)
}
});
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to access the data of the invisible time series `var2` (i.e., `points[1].yval`, here used to determine the length of the vertical line) in the highlightCallback function.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you expect `g.updateOptions(visibility: [true, false])` to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dygraphs does expose a general data access API which you can use from a highlightCallback:

```
g.numRows()
g.numColumns()
g.getValue(row, column)
```

http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#getValue

The "row" parameter to the highlightCallback corresponds to the first parameter to g.getValue().

Here's an example showing how this works:
http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/7/

Comment: Thank you for your help and the provided example! getValue did the job. :)
BTW: Dygraphs is really a great library!

Comment: I have made a small change to your example. The row index that gets passed to `highlightCallback` is always `0` for the leftmost point of the graph. After zooming or panning one has to account for this shift. I used
`row+=g.getLeftBoundary_();`
to offset the row index.

Here is the link to the updated example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/9/)